# How to download a images from url with authentication

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code by which i can download a images from non authentication websites URL. It work fine with those websites, but when i try to download a image by url, website like dropbox. It gives me an error.

Now what i want is this, i want a code by which i can download a images from authenticated and non authenticated website url.

Below is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Users\INTEL\Desktop\Hari\Images\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If your url's are highlighted in blue click on the first one. Excel should open a window where you can authenticate the connection. Enter your username and password for the server and tick checkbox below to save credentials.

If your url's are not highlighted add column next to it with =url(a1) and then click on it.

Once excel remebers your credentials you can execute your script.